# Example where $\limsup A_i \neq \liminf A_i$

Tags: real-analysis

If $A_i$ is a sequence of sets, define$$\liminf_i A_i = \bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \bigcap_{i = j}^\infty A_i, \quad \limsup_i A_i = \bigcap_{j = 1}^\infty \bigcup_{i = j}^\infty A_i.$$What is an example where $\liminf_i A_i \neq \limsup_i A_i$?

Comment: Note: the liminf is "the set of all points in all but finitely many $A_i$", and the limsup is "the set of all points in infinitely many $A_i$"

Comment: You can read the definitions like quantifiers. An element $x$ is in the liminf if and only if there exists $j$ such that for all $i \geq j$, $x \in A_i$. Similarly $x$ is in the limsup if and only if for every $j$ there exists $i \geq j$ such that $x \in A_i$. Thus the liminf is the elements in *all but finitely many* $A_i$ while the limsup is the elements in *infinitely many* $A_i$. In particular the liminf is always a subset of the limsup, and it is a proper subset if there is some $x$ which is in infinitely many $A_i$ and also not in infinitely many $A_i$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A_{2i} = \emptyset$ and $A_{2i+1} = \{1\}$.  You should check that the $\lim \inf$ is then $\emptyset$ while the $\lim \sup$ is $\{1\}$.